# How to set TextView image background from saved path while debugging the phone

Tags: android, null, textview, cursor

I am a bit new in the android world but starting to run already.
I have looked for a satisfying answer for my question and didn't find one.

I am developing and debugging on my **galaxy s II** using **Eclipse**

I am using the bellow code in order to try and load a gallery image from the dscard using a pre-saved image path - and set it as a background to a TextView:

```
String realUri = **getRealPathFromURI**(Uri.parse(imagePath));
_views[i].setBackgroundDrawable(getImageFromUrl(realUri));
```

**cursor from the bellow method returns null**.

```
public String **getRealPathFromURI**(Uri contentUri) {

**contentUri in debug is: "/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/Memeful/Meme 3733.jpg"**

        String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
                        proj,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);

        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

**This is the modified code that worked: 
To be fair, I have gathered it from a few places here, sadly, I didn't come up with it alone**

String imagePathFromUri = uri.getPath();

final Drawable drawable = getImageFromUrl("file://" + imagePathFromUri);

private Drawable getImageFromUrl(String url) {

```
    Drawable d = null;

    try {
        d = Drawable.createFromStream((InputStream) new URL(url).getContent(), "src");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return d;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone sometime..

Thanks a lot,
Eibi

Comment: Solved the problem eventually. Please see my new code at the bottom..